# Pass an array from a php script to another

Tags: php, data-transfer

I call another script with [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), This script returns (`echo()`) a value.
The return value could be anything, array, string, etc.
I can do the transfer with `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`, But is there any other better way (Without use JSON or `$_SESSION['varName']`)?

Comment: show your code. Aside that, json is awesome. why not use it?

Comment: You should explain what do you mean for better and what the issues are with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use PHP's own [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) function. It's native, can encode simple objects, and is less ambiguous than JSON.

Sample code:

```
// page.php
echo serialize($data);
```

And:

```
// receiver.php
$data = file_get_contents('http://example.com/page.php');
if ($data) $data = unserialize($data);
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new. but I'll use JSON, because that serialize is more fat.

Comment: Json is much more readable. Serialize deals better with PHP if you need to encode totally arbitrary data. For most cases though, JSON makes much more sense and it's more portable. I use myself JSON every time I can.